# Can't logout if autologin is enabled on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, gdm

When I try to logout, this screen appears. I can login again by restarting `gdm` (version 3.16.1.1) from a TTY.
I'm running gnome 3.16.3 but I tried on Unity and it's the same problem.

[image]

Last line:

> [ - ] A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit (47s / no limit)